# Given a certificate how can I determine what algorithms and formats are useable with the public key?

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, webcrypto-api

I have a certificate that says the `Signature Algorithm` is `sha256WithRSAEncryption` and the `Key Size` is 1024.

I am trying to encrypt some arbitrary data using the `Web Crypto API` and have only been able to successfully encrypt it by importing the certificate's key with the following params

```
return await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    'spki',
    buffer, // binary format of the key
    {
        name: 'RSA-OAEP',
        hash: 'SHA-256',
    },
    true,
    ['encrypt'],
);
```

And then encrypting the data with the following params

```
await crypto.encrypt({ name: 'RSA-OAEP' }, cryptoKey, chunk); // max of 62 bytes of data given the key size and algorithm
```

My question is, is this the only possible combination to use with this specific key?

The person who issued me the public key says they're expecting an algorithm of `RSA-PKCS1-KeyEx` and a hash of `rsa-sha1` and a data block byte size of 117 for the data to be encrypted with.

Given my very limited understanding of cryptology I am lead to believe that `RSA-PKCS1-KeyEx` can only be used for `signing` and not encrypting, and you typically sign with a private key, not public.

Even changing the params of `importKey` to use `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5` and `sha-1` throws an error that says `Cannot create a key using the specified key usages.`

Is it even possible to use those params with a certificate/key of `sha256WithRSAEncryption` and a keysize of 1024, or is the current way I have it the only possible way to use the key and encrypt the data?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a certificate that says the Signature Algorithm is `sha256WithRSAEncryption` and the Key Size is 1024.

Yeah, OK, but that signature algorithm is for the signature beneath the certificate. That's not the signature algorithm that you need to use for the public or private key contained in the certificate.

> The person who issued me the public key says they're expecting an algorithm of RSA-PKCS1-KeyEx and a hash of rsa-sha1 and a data block byte size of 117 for the data to be encrypted with.

RSA-PKCS1-KeyEx doesn't exist in any standard as far as I know, it's a terrible name for PKCS#1 encryption padding.

Besides that, PKCS#1 v1.5 padding doesn't even use a hash, so specifying SHA-1 just indicates that they have no idea what they are talking about.

> Given my very limited understanding of cryptology I am lead to believe that RSA-PKCS1-KeyEx can only be used for signing and not encrypting, and you typically sign with a private key, not public.

There are two different padding methods specified in the PKCS#1 standard, RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 which is the encryption with PKCS#1 v1.5 padding and RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 which is the signature generation with a different PKCS#1 v1.5 padding.

> Even changing the params of `importKey` to use RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 and sha-1 throws an error that says Cannot create a key using the specified key usages.

Yeah, OK, if the key usage in the certificate just specifies encryption then using a "signature scheme with appendix" or **SSA** is not going to be accepted.

> Is it even possible to use those params with a certificate/key of sha256WithRSAEncryption and a keysize of 1024, or is the current way I have it the only possible way to use the key and encrypt the data?

I only see OAEP specified in WebCrypto. This is probably because PKCS#1 v1.5 padding as you are required to use has been shown to be insecure. SHA-1 is not very secure either and neither is a key size of 1024. So the person that you are talking to doesn't really seem to know much about cryptography (as we commonly call it nowadays) either.

That all said, it might be that the library accepts `rsaEncryption` as algorithm and it may use PKCS#1 v1.5 padding in that case. This option is hidden in the WebCrypto API that defines OAEP. And that in itself shows that they don't know what the heck they are doing as well.